# How does _ftime / Windows internal time work?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, time

I have found an interesting issue in windows which allows me to cause the Windows clock (but not the hardware clocks) to run fast - as much as 8 seconds every minute. I am doing some background research to work out how Windows calculates and updates it's internal time (not how it syncs with an NTP servers). Any information anyone has or any documents you can point me to would be greatly appreciated!

Also, if anyone knows how _ftime works please let me know.

Comment: I'd check for a remote login or a script by a prankster colleague resetting the time...  Sounds like a good way to mess with someone's mind :)  I'm looking forward to seeing what information you get in response to your question, the internal details should be quite interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724961(VS.85).aspx) gives a very brief description of how the system time is handled: "When the system first starts, it sets the system time to a value based on the real-time clock of the computer and then regularly updates the time." Another interesting function is [GetSystemTimeAdjustment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724394.aspx), which has this to say:

> A value of TRUE [for lpTimeAdjustmentDisabled] indicates that periodic time adjustment is disabled. At each clock interrupt, the system merely adds the interval between clock interrupts to the time-of-day clock. The system is free, however, to adjust its time-of-day clock using other techniques. Such other techniques may cause the time-of-day clock to noticeably jump when adjustments are made.

Finally, in regard to _ftime, it appears to be implemented using [GetSystemTimeAsFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724397(VS.85).aspx). So it would wrap directly onto the same built-in time facilities as would be used everywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding how `_ftime()` works:

If you have Microsoft Visual C++ installed, you probably have the C runtime source installed as well. `_ftime()` is defined in `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio <version>\VC\crt\src\ftime.c` and `ftime64.c`.

Answer (score 0):

_ftime doesn't use at all GetSystemTimeAsFileTime. 
Just read the source code.

Comment: It does with the CRT shipped with Visual Studio.NET 2005 through 2012.